# pass null as a value in query string for DataViewWeb Part SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

In dataviewwebpart how to filter with a null field value by passing it through a query string. I am able to do non-null values.

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried empty value? Such as your_url?variable1=&variable2=value2
In this case the first query sting variable actually contains a empty string.